# MSCRM Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm

I have installed sharepint foundation 2013 and added the crmlistcomponent solution. But, the Activate button is disabled. On mouse hover,it says, the control is diasabled for now.You may not have the right permission to use the control. 
I am logged in with the user which I used to install and configure sharepoint.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed. What needs to be done is goto systemsettings and then to manage services on server and start the sp user code service. You cannot start is from services directly as it is disabled.